# delete button to delete a movie card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find the bug in my delete button code, but can't find it. -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**HOME.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import {movies} from "./movies.js"
import Card from "./Card.js"
import "./Home.css"

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            movieslist: movies   
        }
    }

    deleteCard = (removeTitle) => {
        // var newMovieList = [...this.state.movieslist];
        // newMovieList.splice(newMovieList.findIndex(({title}) => title !== removeTitle), 1);
        const newMovieList = this.state.movieslist.filter(movie => movie.title !== removeTitle);
        this.setState({
            movieslist:newMovieList 
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="homecontainer">
                {
                    this.state.movieslist.map(movie => {
                    return <Card delete={this.deleteCard} key={movie.id} title={movie.title} category={movie.category} likes={movie.likes} dislikes={movie.dislikes} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

---

**CARD.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import "./Card.css"

class Card extends PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        active:false
    }

    this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this)
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

toggleClass(){
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
}

handleClick(){
    this.props.delete();
}

render() {
    return (
            <div className="cardbox">
                <div className="cardtitle">{this.props.title}</div>
                <div>{this.props.category}</div>
                <div>{this.props.likes / this.props.dislikes}</div>
                <i onClick={this.toggleClass} className={this.state.active?"fa fa-thumbs-up":"fa fa-thumbs-down"}></i>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button>
            </div>    
    )
}
```

}

export default Card

Comment: Apparently you were getting the message that says (more or less) "This is just a wall of code; perhaps you can provide some explanation with it?"  Repeating the same sentence over and over again is not what we had in mind.

Comment: apologies for that: that was indeed what happened!

Comment: Make sure to include the encountered error/problem inside the question (you should update this question to avoid seeing it be deleted for being "unclear/lacking details"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the state wrong.

You put the new state to newMovieList and not to movieslist.

So change it to:

```
deleteCard = (removeTitle) => {
    var newMovieList = [...this.state.movieslist];
    newMovieList.splice(newMovieList.findIndex(({title}) => title === removeTitle), 1);
    this.setState({
        movieslist:newMovieList 
    })
}
```

Update:

```
You are not passing the title in DeletCard. Change it to:

handleClick(){
     this.props.delete(this.props.title);
}
```

You can improve your code a bit:

```
var newMovieList = [...this.state.movieslist];
newMovieList.splice(newMovieList.findIndex(({title}) => title === removeTitle), 1);
```

can be

```
const newMovieList = this.state.movieslist.filter(movie => movie.title !== removeTitle);
```

And to reduce the length of your code:

```
 render() {
    const {title, category, likes, dislikes } = this.props;
    return (
            <div className="cardbox">
                <div className="cardtitle">{title}</div>
                <div>{category}</div>
                <div>{likes / dislikes}</div>
                <i onClick={this.toggleClass} className={this.state.active?"fa fa-thumbs-up":"fa fa-thumbs-down"}></i>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button>
            </div>    
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks very helpful! a problem that I am having now is that it deletes always the last element and not the one clicked...why is that?

Comment: I forgot a !, check my answer.

Comment: thanks, also wondering if you need to declare the variable newMovieList as it's still not working

Comment: Sure you have to put const in front of it

Comment: Thanks! I tried using this method: const newMovieList = this.state.movieslist.filter(movie => movie.title !== removeTitle), but now nothing disappears anymore when I click a delete button

Comment: someone that can have another look at this? I just updated my code at the top!